# Можно ли обеспечить поддержку ActionScript 2.0 с помощью Adobe Flash CC?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, совместимость

Сделал баннер в Adobe Flash CC и написал к нему в Actionscript 3 маленький код для перехода на сайт по клику мышки, а заказчик развернул баннер, сказав, что необходима совместимость баннера с ActionScript 2 и adobe flash player 9.

Можно ли как то в версии CC написать код, совместимый с actionscript 2 или же нужно ставить другую версию flash с прямой поддержкой ActionScript 2 (cs3, например) и все делать по новой?

Прошу ответы давать в как можно более доступной форме так как я начинающий в ActionScript.

Comment: Я не сварщик, просто мимо проходил. Но может то что по ссылке поможет?https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1235279

Comment: Если не боитесь взяться за новый язык, то компилятор haxe с генератором AVM1 собирает флэшки для плееров версии аж от 6ой, а AVM2 -- от 9ой. Синтаксис максимально похож на AS3, есть даже автоматические преобразователи в haxe. [Почитайте.](http://haxe.org/manual/target-flash-getting-started.html)

Comment: Нет сс не поддерживает as2. Он уже умер. И да, придется все сначала делать. Есть вроде какие-то мосты, который Скинер написал, но легче перенести, открыть прям две версии программы и копипостить.

Comment: Adobe Flash Player 9 поддерживает AS3, так что скорее всего можно будет обойтись версией баннера, собранной под 9й флеш (там, правда, много чего нет, векторов, например), то есть придется править код. Советую для начала скомпилировать проект под Flash 9, оттестировать и результат отправить заказчику. Если же попросит AS2, сказать, что он таки умер.